# Token not allowed warning for hebrew numeral?

Tags: hyperref, polyglossia

I am using Latex to do my homework, and I write in our native language Hebrew. I am using `polyglossia` to configure the language settings and fonts in the document and `hyperref` to add links wherever I need.

I recently wanted to add a table of contents so it will be easier to navigate the document. One fantastic feature of hyperref is that the TOC contains links that allow me to easily jump to where I want in the document (Honestly, I think it should be a default feature of TOC).

However, I encountered a weird issue when trying to add the TOC. I am using custom counters for questions and different parts of the question/answer, and I number the parts with letters such as:

סעיף א,
סעיף ב,
סעיף ג

which translates to:
Part A, Part B, Part C, ...

A simplified version of the code to achieve this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=blue
}

% Font and language settings
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[
    Script=Hebrew,
    ItalicFont=*-Regular,
    ItalicFeatures={FakeSlant=0.3},
]{Assistant}

\setmainlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setsansfont{Assistant}
\setmonofont{Assistant}

\newcounter{ProblemNum}
\newcounter{SubProblemNum}[ProblemNum]

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TheProblemNum}{}{\arabic{ProblemNum}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\TheSubProblemNum}{}{\alph{SubProblemNum}} % <- This causes the warnings

\NewDocumentCommand{\Problem}{ o }{
    \stepcounter{ProblemNum}

    % Add the "unnumbered" subsections to TOC
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{שאלה \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#1}{\; #1}}
    \subsection*{שאלה \TheProblemNum \IfNoValueF{#1}{\; #1}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Solution}{}{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{פתרון}
    \subsubsection*{פתרון}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Part}{}{
    \stepcounter{SubProblemNum}
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{סעיף \TheSubProblemNum}
    \subsubsection*{סעיף \TheSubProblemNum}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\Problem
דוגמה לשאלה
\Solution
\Part
פתרון לסעיף הראשון.
\Part
פתרון לסעיף השני.
\end{document}
```

I am using the font [Assistant](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant).

The problem is that when compiling with multipart questions, I get warnings:
`Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing \@hebrew@numeral`. I understand that it happens because I use `\alph{SubProblemNum}` for the answer's parts. Changing to `\arabic{SubProblemNum}` removes the warnings. The strange thing is that after compiling the document looks fine, so it appears the warnings are harmless:

[image]

How can I fix these warnings or, at least, suppress them?

Comment: please don't show only snippets. Always make a small but complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I edited to add a complete example

Comment: This will be solved in the next release of polyglossia. See https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/pull/596

Answer (score 2):

A simpler example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\setmainlanguage{hebrew}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{mycounter}{5}

\section{Text \alph{mycounter} more text}

\end{document}
```

There is no problem in the document:

[image]

hyperref complains because it can't correctly process the `\alph` command (which internally calls `\@hebrew@numeral` for the bookmarks (the PDF outline/navigation)

[image]

There is not much one can do to correct this. The current definition of `\@hebrew@numeral` command is quite unexpandable and hyperref has really no chance to do something sensible here. The command would need a complete rewrite to work also in bookmarks. You can suppress the processing (and so the warning) by using `\texorpdfstring{\alph{mycounter}}{}` but it is up to you to decide if this good enough for you.